# "The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2020/05."-when uploading a media, getting this error on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have already tried changing the following to get this issue fixed but still didn't work:

1. changing permission to 777,755,744,766,644
2. change in wp-config.php

   ```
   define('UPLOADS','wp-content/uploads');
   require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php' );
   ```

   Please Note: I don't have this option in media settings (settings > media)

Blockquote store uploads in this folder.

Comment: does the whole directory structure have the right persmission? not only uploads?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to define UPLOADS - WordPress knows where to find its upload directory, and changing the defaults may cause issues later, so start by removing the 'define...' line from your wp-config file.

On the server, I'm assuming you're on some kind of linux box (you don't specify), but the first thing to do is find out what user the server is running the Apache web process under.

```
ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
```

This will list all running apache processes, and in the first column you should see the user - on mine, it's www-data. You may see some with root as the user, ignore those.

```
www-data 22052  1.0  3.3 482980 135680 ?       S    11:50   0:03 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Knowing the user now allows us to make sure that user has permissions to write to the WordPress directory as a whole - this includes making changes to the .htaccess files to update symlinks, as well as installing plugins, updates, and uploading files and media.

Navigate to the main wp-directory containing your wp-config.php file and run `ls -l`

You should see a list of all the files with the user and group associated with them, and their permission. Don't change permissions here. You should find most or all of the files have that same apache user (again, mine is www-data) as the owner of the files - the first column.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data customuser  3168 Apr  3 13:58 wp-config.php
```

Now we want to make sure every file and directory in the install is owned by this user, so that it can make changes based on the specific r/w privileges assigned. **Make sure you're in your WordPress directory before doing this!**

Replace 'www-data' here with whatever user you determined apache is running under from the previous step. 'www-data' is correct on my server, but it may be different on yours.

```
chown -R www-data *
```

This changes the ownership [chown] recursively [-R], on the files in the directory, as well as any files and directories nested within the directory, to [www-data] the user we determined the web service is running under [*] to everything.

Test and see if that fixes the problem.

If not, navigate to the actual standard location of the uploads directory.

[your-wp-root-folder]/wp-content

run `ls -l` again

```
 drwxr-xr-x 14 www-data www-data 4096 Apr  3 13:47 uploads
```

The permissions are at the start - [drwxr-xr-x]

[d] - directory

[rwx] owner has read/write/execute - 7

[r-x] group has read/--/execute - 5

[r-x] everyone has read/--/execute - 5

So this would be 755 permissions

You can use chmod to change permissions here:

```
chmod -R 755 ./uploads
```

[./uploads] the [.] means 'start in the current directory', the [/uploads] means 'affect the uploads directory'. [-R] as before makes the change recursively, so it will affect any files and directories contained within the uploads directory.

This should fix any permissions issues on the upload directory.